# Move "Favorites" font collection to another machine

Tags: migration, font

On my old laptop I had a moderate-sized collection of "favorites" fonts that I've set over the past few years. The laptop is now gone, but I have a disk image with the entire contents of the hard drive. Is there a way I can copy the fonts that were in the "Favorites" collection to my new computer? Put another way, is there a file I can copy from one machine to the other which contains my "Favorites" fonts collection? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

Before you do, your font library on your new computer should probably contain the same fonts as the old one. *(I’m not entirely sure this is necessary, but I suggest it to be on the safe side).*

OS X stores most of its fonts in one of three locations:

- `~/Library/Fonts` — fonts you’ve installed for your personal use;
- `/Library/Fonts` — fonts you’ve installed for every user on the computer;
- `/System/Library/Fonts/` — the fonts that Mac OS X *needs*.

You’ll probably only need to transfer fonts from the first two folders, as your new installation of OS X will provide the fonts in the third. More detail in the [Apple support article on font locations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2435).

If you’ve got the odd font that isn’t in one of these three folders, you can still find its location. Open the file `~/Library/Fonts/fonts.list` in a text editor (TextEdit would do). The file contains a long list of font locations, which correspond to the fonts that you’ve installed. With this, you can find any fonts that are lurking elsewhere.

---

Once you have your old font library on your new computer, transferring the font collections should be relatively easy. On the disk image of the old laptop, navigate to `~/Library/FontCollections`. One of these files will be `Favourites.collection` (or whatever you called it). Copy this file to `~/Library/FontCollections` of your new computer, and then the collection should show up in Font Book the next time you launch it.